# Critical section

Tags: operating-system

How the below solution **doesn't satisfy the solution criteria of critical section problem**?

Which of the three situations it is not satisfying?
1. Mutual exclusion
2. Progress
3. Bounded Waiting

I know that it is satisfying Mutual exclusion but **what about 2 & 3?**
Please note that this is not a homework. I have thought a lot but still not clear.

[EDIT]
Removed picture & added code.

```
Pi’s Algorithm    
    Var flag : array [ i…j] of boolean    
    repeat  
    flag [i] = true;    
While ( flag [j]  == “ true ”) do no-op;        


            Critical section


Flag [i]=“ false ”;
 until false
```

Another process

```
Pj’s Algorithm    
    Var flag : array [ i…j] of boolean
repeat  
  flag [ j ] = true;
While ( flag [ i ]  == “ true ”) do no-op;  


        Critical section


Flag [j]=“ false ”;
 until false
```

Comment: This is a question from an interview in which they asked why peterson problem fails if only one variable is taken? So, i wrote code for only one variable flag & left the other[turn]. Now, i am not able to figure out how this fails?

Answer (score 0):

The system may be deadlocking:

2 Processes: P1, P2. I assume i and j are the processes' IDs and are shared variables, as is the flags array.

Then P1 starts executing:

```
flag[1] := true;
```

-> here P1 gets interrupted by the scheduler and P2 starts running:

```
flag[2] := true;
while (flag[1] == true) do nop ;
```

-> P2 remains in this loop. Later the scheduler picks P1 again:

```
while (flag[2] == true) do nop;
```

-> P1 gets stuck in the loop as well. No progress. This deadlocks, hence violates #2 and #3. Furthermore, it is also possible that one of the processes gets starved (the other always runs through the whole code and never gets interrupted between flag[i] := false and flag[i] := true, so that the first process never gets a chance to leave the while loop.

Comment: I agree with you. But, don't you think that such type of conditions can also happen in PETERSON's solution but still it is proved that it provides solution to critical section problem. Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849077/unable-to-understand-correctness-of-peterson-algorithm