# Concurrent Processing - Petersons Algorithm

Tags: deadlock, concurrent-programming

For those unfamiliar, the following is Peterson's algorithm used for process coordination:

```
int No_Of_Processes; // Number of processes
int turn; // Whose turn is it?
int interested[No_Of_Processes]; // All values initially FALSE

void enter_region(int process) {
int other; // number of the other process

other = 1 - process; // the opposite process
interested[process] = TRUE; // this process is interested
turn = process; // set flag
while(turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE); // wait
}

void leave_region(int process) {
interested[process] = FALSE; // process leaves critical region
}
```

My question is, can this algorithm give rise to deadlock?

Comment: Dammit, I found a dupe, but it is closed a not a real question (what?), and is very poorly formulated. So I won't vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no deadlock possible.
The only place you are waiting is `while` loop. And the `process` variables is not shared between threads and they are different, but `turn` variable is shared. So it's impossible to get `true` condition for `turn == process` for more then one thread in every single moment.
But anyway your solution is not correct at all, the Peterson's algorithm is only for two concurrent threads, not for any `No_Of_Processes` like in your code.
In original algorithm for `N` processes deadlocks are possible [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033738/does-petersons-algorithm-satisfy-starvation).